# when calling void with throws keyword, all thrown errors apply to where i call the void

Tags: java, awt, awtrobot, throws, jnativehook

i am currently trying to make a shift key holder with java using the grave accent as the toggle and robot was the only way i could find that was remotely simple. the program does what the name implies, and holds down the shift key for me. making the program for starbound building if you are wondering where this will be useful, as there is capslock. however when using robot i have to throw a few exceptions, but they then appear in the place that i am calling my void

i can't find any solution for this possibly because i am using the JNativeHook  library to create a keylogger that will react to the grave symbol. i am still fairly new and i pieced a lot of this together from snippets online.

this is where my error is coming from, the full program is available [here](https://github.com/Vortetty/js-hosting-/blob/master/com/vortetty/Main.java)
i would post a minimum reproducible example but i cannot as i don't know what parts are crucial to the function of this one part.

```java
//tried to put throws in nativeKeyPressed to get rid of the exceptions but then that gives me an exception saying i can't do that because it causes clashing
public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e){
        System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));

        if (e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_BACKQUOTE) {
            toggle(); //get IOException, AWTException, and InterruptedException whenever i put throws on my toggle() void
        }
    }

        //throw exceptions so robot has no conflicts
    public static void toggle() throws IOException, AWTException, InterruptedException{
        bool = !bool;
        Robot r = new Robot();

        if (bool = true) {

        } else if (bool = false) {

        }
```

i expect it to have no errors but `Robot()` has exceptions if i dont throw them, and `toggle();` has whatever exceptions i throw from `public static void toggle()`. i am open to methods other than robot, but i cant find any others.

Comment: Not sure if I'm misunderstanding here, but have you tried just surrounding your toggle() call in a try catch? It's an unhandled exception.

Comment: @amir how would i do this, i am stumbling in the dark here trying to figure this out, taking a java course and the most recent thing i have learned is how to call a void. but of couse i need the program that uses things i have not learned yet.

Comment: `if (bool = true) {` is always true, because it's an assignment, not a comparison. Use `bool == true`, or, better, `bool` (and `bool == false` or `!bool`).

Comment: @AndyTurner thank you for catching that, i would not have for a while

Comment: Related or possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589302/why-is-throws-exception-necessary-when-calling-a-function

Comment: @Tom this question is completely different as i have exceptions that are known and able to be handled whereas they have exceptions that have yet to be handled and are causing them to throw an unknown exception, whereas me throwing my exceptions has caused further issue, and needs resolved. however i see why it may seem related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are expecting any of these exceptions and know how to handle them, just wrap your exceptions

```
public static void rethrowException (Exception ex) {
  throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
    //throw exceptions so robot has no conflicts
public static void toggle() {
  try {
    bool = !bool;
    Robot r = new Robot();

    if (bool = true) {

    } else if (bool = false) {

    }
  } catch (IOException|AWTException|InterruptedException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
  }
}
```

Comment: this has been tested, and has not removed the error, i actually gain more errors

Comment: @ControlAltDel I guess you meant to remove the throws too :) but why not just throw the runtime exception directly? What does the method provide?

Comment: @AndyTurner yessiree!

Comment: @AndyTurner fixed my exception handling

Comment: @AndyTurner you code seems to have worked, all exceptions are gone, and it turns out using this method prevents me from needing to catch IOException and InteruptedException! thank you to all of you!