# Why does it say file not found when im trying to make a file

Tags: java

I'm trying to practice with file creation and I'm copying the code straight off my book but getting an error

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class JavaFilePractice {        

    public static void main(String[] args){
        

        String filename;
        filename = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the file name");
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(filename);

        outputFile.println("Jim");

    }
}
```

The error is

> Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException

Comment: What error? [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78039222/edit) your question to include the exact error message and stacktrace.

Comment: @Chaosfire editted

Comment: That's compilation error `FileNotFoundException` is checked exception, you need to either handle it in `try catch` block, or declare that the main method throws it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is "throws Exception" necessary when calling a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589302/why-is-throws-exception-necessary-when-calling-a-function)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a throws declaration. And you should use a try-catch with resources to ensure that the writer is closed

```java
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class JavaFilePractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        final String filename = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the file name");
        try (final PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(filename)) {
            outputFile.println("Jim");
        }
    }
}
```

Errors happen. Even in books.